# How to display a list and fields using Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

pretty new  to mvc 5.

I have a model that contains a field and a list.

I wish to display both in my view.

this is my model:

```
public class AdminChargeHistory
{
    public List<StripeChargeHistory> Charges = new List<StripeChargeHistory>();
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set;] }
}

public class StripeChargeHistory
{
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public string AmountRefunded { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Paid { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string ChargeId { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public string BalanceTransId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Live { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Month { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Year { get; set; }
}
```

my controller:

```
public ActionResult MissedPayments()
{
    var adminChargeHistory = new AdminChargeHistory();
    try
    {
        var stripeRepository = new StripeRepository();               
        var results = stripeRepository.GetMissedPayments(-1, -1, false);
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            var stripeChargeHistory = new StripeChargeHistory();
            stripeChargeHistory.Amount = result.Amount;
            stripeChargeHistory.AmountRefunded = result.AmountRefunded;
            stripeChargeHistory.BalanceTransId = result.BalanceTransId;
            stripeChargeHistory.ChargeId = result.ChargeId;
            stripeChargeHistory.CustomerId = result.CustomerId;
            stripeChargeHistory.InvoiceId = result.InvoiceId;
            stripeChargeHistory.Live = result.Live;
            stripeChargeHistory.Month = result.Month;
            stripeChargeHistory.Paid = result.Paid;
            stripeChargeHistory.Status = result.Status;
            stripeChargeHistory.TransactionId = result.TransactionId;
            stripeChargeHistory.Year = result.Year;
            adminChargeHistory.Charges.Add(stripeChargeHistory);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        adminChargeHistory.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
    }

    return View(adminChargeHistory);
}
```

my view:

```
@model InformedProducts.Models.AdminChargeHistory
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Missed Payments";
}

<h2>Missed Payments</h2>
<table class="grid">
    <tr>
        <th>Customer Id</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Year</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.StripeChargeHistory)
    {

        <tr>
            <td class="left"><@item.CustomerId></td>
            <td class="left"><@item.Amount></td>
            <td class="left"><@item.Month></td>
            <td class="left"><@item.Year></td>
        </tr>

    @}
    @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.ErrorMessage)
</table>
```

but errors here:

```
InformedProducts.Models.AdminChargeHistory
```

and here?
    @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.ErrorMessage)

I cannot see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `"but errors here"` - And the errors are...?

Comment: Just says not found in the design view

Comment: For starters, there's a typo in your `AdminChargeHistory` class which would prevent it from compiling.  So you definitely can't use it until it at least compiles.  Surely the compiler is telling you about *that* error?  As for "not found" could you show maybe a screen shot of it?  Usually there's something more descriptive.

Comment: Hi David. That would just be a copy and paste error. The design errors just come up with a squiggly line under those 2 items. Have I declared  my model inside my view correctly? Am away from PC at mo but will do screenshot ASAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model - Add getter/setter for Charges and empty constructor.

```
public class AdminChargeHistory
{
    public AdminChargeHistory()
    {
        Charges = new List<StripeChargeHistory>();
    }

    public ICollection<StripeChargeHistory> Charges { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Controller - take advantage of LINQ

```
public ActionResult MissedPayments()
{
    var adminChargeHistory = new AdminChargeHistory();
    try
    {
        var stripeRepository = new StripeRepository();
        var results = stripeRepository.GetMissedPayments(-1, -1, false);

        adminChargeHistory.Charges = results.Select(result => new StripeChargeHistory
        {
            Amount = result.Amount,
            CustomerId = result.CustomerId,
            Month = result.Month,
            Year = result.Year
        }).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        adminChargeHistory.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
    }

    return View(adminChargeHistory);
}
```

View - Reference the Charges collection property

```
@model InformedProducts.Models.AdminChargeHistory
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Missed Payments";
}

<h2>Missed Payments</h2>
<table class="grid">
    <tr>
        <th>Customer Id</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Year</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Charges)
    {

        <tr>
            <td class="left"><@item.CustomerId></td>
            <td class="left"><@item.Amount></td>
            <td class="left"><@item.Month></td>
            <td class="left"><@item.Year></td>
        </tr>

    @}
    @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.ErrorMessage)
</table>
```

if you have red squiggly under `@model InformedProducts.Models.AdminChargeHistory` you might have the wrong namespace.. Remove `InformedProducts.Models.` and put cursor on `AdminChargeHistory` and hit ctrl + . (period) and it should find the correct namespace.

Comment: great answer - i keep forgetting about using linq like that. Though am I right in assuming I do not have to have a  constructor>? As I have not included one and it works ok

Comment: @AndrewSimpson in this case you probably don't need it. I like to do it to avoid null reference errors in the future

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Charges)
{
    // code removed for brevity...
}
```

This is because your model `AdminChargeHistory` has a property named `Charges` which is enumerable. What you are using right now: `Model.StripeChargeHistory` won't work because there is no such property in the class `AdminChargeHistory`.

Also, you have `public string ErrorMessage { get; set;] }`, that bracket looks like a problem.

Comment: I believe ur right. Am away from PC at mo but will respond ASAP. Thanks for your answer

Comment: sorry for the delay in my response. This was obviously correct for that part - thanks